# Testing if a collection contains objects based on a particular property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections, nunit, nunit-2.5

I'm using NUnit 2.5.7.  I want to test whether a collection of custom objects of a particular class contains certain objects, based on one of the class's properties.

e.g. a contrived example...

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

// ...

public List<Person> GetFavouritePeople()
{
   List<Person> favouritePeople = new List<Person>();
   favouritePeople.Add(new Person("joe"));
   favouritePeople.Add(new Person("fred"));
   favouritePeople.Add(new Person("jenny"));

   return favouritePeople;
}

// ... 

[Test]
public GetFavouritePeople()
{
    List<Person> people = GetFavouritePeople();

    // What I'd like to test, but not sure how to do it...
    Assert.Contains(Name="joe", people);
    Assert.Contains(Name="fred", people);
    Assert.Contains(Name="jenny", people);
}
```

Although it would be simple enough in this example, I don't want to create mock objects for each Person and use those in the assertion... I just want to check based on a particular property (Name in this example.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
Assert.That(people.Any(p => p.Name == "joe"));
```

or, if you want to be explicit about there being exactly one person with each name:

```
Assert.That(people.Count(p => p.Name == "joe"), Is.EqualTo(1));
```

If you want a better error message than "Assertion failed, expected true, was false", you could create your own assert method.

For several collection-related asserts, `CollectionAssert` is very useful - for instance, it allows you to check if two collections contain the same elements, irrespective of their order. So yet another possibility is:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new[] {"joe", "fred", "jenny"}, people.Select(p => p.Name).ToList());
```

Note that `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()` is a little picky with regard to the types it accepts (even though the signature takes `IEnumerable`). I usually wrap it in another method that calls `ToList()` on both parameters before invoking `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()`.

Comment: How would you write this for Xunit?

Comment: @Enrico: Looks like `Assert.All()` and `Assert.Contains()`: https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/CollectionAsserts.cs

Comment: I couldn't find a way to check if an array contains an object that has a property which has a certain value. Solved it by doing this:

            Assert.Contains(result.Value.Members, x => x.Consumption == null);

Answer (score 18):

You can use `Assert.That` in conjunction with `Has.Exactly(1).Matches`:

```
List<Person> people = GetFavouritePeople()
Assert.That(people, Has.Exactly(1).Matches<Person>(p => p.Name == "NUnit is amazing")));
```

Failure message will be along lines of:

> Expected: exactly one item value matching lambda expression
> But was:  0 items < [result of people.ToString()] >

Answer (score 4):

You can use Linq's [`Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine whether all the expected items are within the list your testing against even if the list contains other items that you are not testing for:

```
[Test]
public void TestFavouritePeople()
{
    var people = GetFavouritePeople();
    var names = people.Select(p => p.Name);

    var expectedNames = new[] {"joe", "fred", "jenny"};
    var actualNames = names.Intersect(expectedNames);

    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedNames, actualNames);
}
```

For NUnit 3.0 and greater, you can use [`Is.SupersetOf()`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/CollectionSupersetConstraint):

```
[Test]
public void TestFavouritePeople()
{
    var people = GetFavouritePeople();
    var names = people.Select(p => p.Name);

    var expectedNames = new[] {"joe", "fred", "jienny"};
    var actualNames = names;

    Assert.That(actualNames, Is.SupersetOf(expectedNames)); 
}
```